# Function to copy data in a reference char array

Tags: c++, function, pass-by-reference

How can I write in C++ a function who put the data in a char array, I don't how to explain well but I'll write an example

```
void functionCopyData(char& buf){
   // get data from a char variable
   char data1 = "textdata1";
   char data2 = "textdata2"

   // copy data
   copy(&buf,data1);
   copy(&buf,data2);
}

char variable[20];

functionCopyData(&variable);    
printf(variable);
// return: textdata1textdata2
```

So summarizing, I need to copy the data from two variables and put in a char array. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Why this way?

because I need to get the data from and a variable and send it in a function request a reference data `sendFunction(&data,sizeVar);`

how can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use C-style strings (`char[]`), rather than the `std::string` of C++?

Comment: yes it's because I'm doing this script for Arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I write in C++ a function who put the data in a char array

1. Change the argument type.

   ```
   void functionCopyData(char& buf){
   ```

   will be good if you want to update just one character, not an array of characters. To update an array of characters, use:

   ```
   void functionCopyData(char buf[]){
   ```

   or

   ```
   void functionCopyData(char* buf){
   ```

   That could easily lead to problems if `buf` does not have enough memory to store the data. To make function more robust, pass a number that indicates the capacity of `buf`.

   ```
   void functionCopyData(char buf[], size_t capacity){
   ```
2. Fix the definitions of `data1` and `data2`.

   ```
   char data1 = "textdata1";
   char data2 = "textdata2"
   ```

   are not syntactically valid. Change them to:

   ```
   char data1[] = "textdata1";
   char data2[] = "textdata2";
   ```

   or

   ```
   char const* data1 = "textdata1";
   char const* data2 = "textdata2";
   ```
3. Make sure that `buf` can hold `data1` and `data2`.

   ```
   // You need the additional 1 for the terminating null
   // character.
   size_t capacityNeeded = strlen(data1) + strlen(data2) + 1;
   if ( capacityNeeded > capacity )
   {
      // Deal with the problem.
   }
   else
   {
       // Now copy the contents of data1 and data2 to buf
   }
   ```
4. Copy the contents `data1` and `data2` to `buf` using standard library functions.

   ```
   strcpy(buf, data1);
   strcat(buf, data2);
   ```
5. Fix the call to the function.

   ```
   functionCopyData(&variable);
   ```

   is not the right syntax to use to call the function, given the function declaration. Use:

   ```
   functionCopyData(variable, 20);
   ```

Comment: The result of that function is te equivalent to this?:`char var[20] = {'t','e','x','t'}` if it's not, how can I do that?

Comment: @GEPD, you said you want the result to be `textdata1textdata2`. If you want the result to be `text`, you are asking a completely different question.

Comment: Yes I thought that was the way to do it, but tested it now and I'm having different results. The way to do it is changing strcpy for a loop?

Comment: @GEPD, If I understand what you are saying correctly, you want the result to be `textdata1textdata2` but you are not getting that result. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: I'm getting this result: `textdata1textdata2` but when I see the output in the device who is receiving the data, it is received it like `textdata1textdata2▒▒▒▒▒`. But if I manually send the data with this variable `char var[20] = {'t','e','x','t'}` it shows `text` and not `text▒▒▒▒▒` I don't know if I explained it better

Comment: @GEPD, that makes sense. I am guessing that you are sending the number of bytes also when sending `var`. If that is true, send `strlen(var)` instead of sending `sizeof(var)`.

Comment: You are totally right, my mistake was I was doing `sizeof` instead of `strlen` now all is working fine, thanks for your support, it really help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to write a function to copy one array, and then call it twice with different pointers pointing to different positions in the result array.

For example, if you have `char data[20]` to hold the result, and want to copy two arrays `char a[10]` and `char b[10]`, then write a function

```
void copy(char* destination, char* source, int length)
```

That copies `length` bytes from source to destination, then call it with

```
copy(data, a, 10);
copy(data+10, b, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) and [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) can help you:

```
#include <string.h>

void functionCopyData(char buf[]){
  char data1[] = "textdata1";
  char data2[] = "textdata2";

  strcpy(buf, data1);
  strcpy(buf+strlen(buf), data2);
}

...
functionCopyData(variable);
...
```

Comment: This is closer than I want, but I have a little issue. Look, I'm sending this information with a RF module in Arduino to a Raspberry Pi (python)

The thing is when I send the data with this function in the Raspberry Pi I receive it but with a weird simbols. But if I do this `char var[20] = {'t','e','x','t'}` I received it correctly.

Is the previous function equivalent to the previous sentence?

Comment: Your language is slightly unclear (Is a function equivalent to a sentence?), but I think you misunderstand arrays. When you declare `char var[20] = {'t','e','x','t'}`, the trailing 16 elements of the array contain *something*. If you don't see them on the Pi, it's because your Pi is using some convention of not printing certain characters. Either you care about the value of those elements or you don't, and if you do then you should tell us what they should be.

Comment: Excuse me for my language, I know I've been a little confusing.
My problem is when I use the function, it does what I was asking for. But when I see the output in the RPi it is a little different to what I was expecting. It shows the text  `textdata1textdata2` and after that 3 or 4 weird simbols. However if I manually create this kind of array `char var[20] = {'t','e','x','t'}` The output in the RPi is what I expected `text` without any weird simbol. So, why with the function I get that simbols?

Comment: @GEPD: Because the characters after `text` differ from the characters after `textdata1textdata2`, and your Pi does something different with them.

Comment: Well the mystake wasn't because the function, when I sended the data I was using `sizeof` instead of `strlen` it was all the problem, but thanks you, your function help me much too!

Answer (score 0):

```
 void functionCopyData(char* buf){
   // get data from a char variable
   char* data1 = "textdata1";
   char* data2 = "textdata2"

   // copy data
   copy(buf,data1);
   copy(buf,data2);
}

char variable[20];

functionCopyData(variable);    
printf(variable);
```

I think it's more clear use pointer but not reference.